# CSS 100% height not working with a custom tag

Tags: html, css, custom-tag

[image]I have html and body set to 100% and same  with loading-view but loading view doesn't have 100% height.

```
body {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 98%;
    width: 98%;
    display: table;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}
@font-face{

font-family:CaviarDreamsBold;
 src:url('CaviarDreamsBold.ttf');

}
/*
**** Circular Selection ****
*/

.CircularSelectionView {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.CircularSelectionObject {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
}
.CircularObjectIcon {
    width: 100%;
    height: 75%;
}
.CircularObjectTitle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
/*
**** Loading ****
*/

loading-view {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
loading-content {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.loaderAnimator {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
.wordElement {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 12px;
    background-color: #d9975e;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18pt;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
/*
**** Tab View ****
*/

tab-view {
    display: table;
}
tab-bar {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
}
.tabBarButton {
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    color: #999999;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 5px 0px;
    padding: 3px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: CaviarDreamsBold, "Arial", sans-serif;
    /*-webkit-transition: background-color 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color 1.0s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color 1.0s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color 1.0s linear;
    transition: background-color 1.0s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    -moz-transition: color 1.0s linear;
    -o-transition: color 1.0s linear;
    -ms-transition: color 1.0s linear;
    transition: color 1.0s linear;*/
}
tab-content {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
tab-item {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

html

```
    <!---->

    <loading-view>
        <loading-content>
            <tool-bar></tool-bar>

            <tab-view id="tabView">
                <tab-bar></tab-bar>

                <tab-content>
                    <!-- First tab-content will show on page load -->
                    <tab-item data-title="Meat Pizzas">
                        <circular-view id="exampleView" data-object-class="exampleObject" data-autoloop-interval="1000 ">
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">0</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">1</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">2</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">3</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">4</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">5</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">6</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">7</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">8</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">9</circular-object>
                            <circular-object data-icon="Resources/ExamplePizza.png">10</circular-object>
                            <!-- Last object in the list is the
                first to be featured on page load -->
                        </circular-view>
                    </tab-item>

                    <tab-item data-title="Second Thing">
                        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:gray;">
                            View 2
                        </div>
                    </tab-item>

                    <tab-item data-title="Third Thing">
                        <div style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color:lightgray;">
                            View 3
                        </div>
                    </tab-item>
                </tab-content>


            </tab-view>


        </loading-content>
    </loading-view>

</body>
```

Comment: Any reason you are using non-standard HTML? It's highly likely that this will cause compatibility bugs between browsers. On which note, you haven't told us which browser(s) you have tested this in.

Comment: This is in chrome. and i was processing it with javascript to make it easier for changing stuff like the toolbar on every page.

Comment: Not sure how using non-standard HTML makes it easier to change anything - it's a very unusual approach - but I guess that's up to you.

Comment: yea its only for a school project so it does't matter too much. There will be 4 or so pages and changing something will be annoying changing on 4 pages

Comment: Unless it's the cause of this issue, I guess!

Comment: Removing all the stuff in the body and making a div and giving it a style that has the same stuff as the loading-view in the css gives it 100% width but not height.

Comment: @IMSoP Custom elements are [being standardized](http://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/), and aren't the cause of the problem. Also see [html5rocks article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom element has 100% height of `<body>`, but you need to make `<body>` 100% height of `<html>`.

The problems with your

```
body {
    min-height: 98%;
    display: table;
}
```

are that

- `min-height` has no effect in tables.
- percentage `height` only works if parent has a explicitly specified `height` (i.e., it doesn't depend on content height), which is not the case with `min-height`.

Then, you must use

```
body {
    height: 98%;
}
```

instead of the code above.

Comment: Body does have the expected height when i use `min-height:98%`. Removing body `display: table` didnt work/

Comment: @user1726450 No, because `min-height` has no effect in tables. I have updated the answer explaining it better.

Comment: Only having height:98% worked but since I removed table why doesnt min work?

Comment: @user1726450 Because `min-height` is just a restriction for `height`, but doesn't specify explicitly a height.